# How do we move subdivided things "correctly"?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, workflow

Is there a nice way to move my edges, so that the active vertex' position is exactly (0,0,0) when SubsurfModifier is active?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you enabled Adjust Cage to modifier's result in modifier's properties then the vertices won't be displayed in their original places, rather than where they will be once the modifier is applied. Disable that setting and you will see actual vertices' positions

Comment: I have edited my question. Guess that part was misleading...

Comment: How is Subsurf related here then? Local coordinates depend on origin point. If you really want to see 0,00000 in the X field then toggle Global coordinates below the fields panel. And vertex position will differ anyway if Subsurf is enabled for previewing in Edit mode like on the 2-nd screenshot.

Comment: How far to the right do I need to move my edges so that the active vertex in 2nd image is coincident with the origin and the 3D cursor? (I could duplicate the object, apply modifiers, draw edge from that point to the origin and measure it. But that's tedious and not really a nice solution...)

Answer (score 1):

To do this computationally would be a headache. Every surface point is influenced by multiple control points, there is infinite number of solutions and without some constraints (a 2d plane, some symmetry constraints, etc) it's non-trivial.

The trivial solution is:

1. The objective is to place the marked surface vertex at (0,0,0):

   [image]
2. Copy the object and apply the subd modifier. Measure how far the point is from (0,0,0):

   [image]
3. Delete the duplicate and move the original object inverse of what you measured. If you don't want to move the whole object, you have to move the control geometry surrounding the point in question (all vertices that influence the location of that point)

Comment: But Blender probably knows where that active vertex is when the modifier is active. That at least would make some sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: @marcus Sure, but how will you specify such vertex when the modifier is not applied? You can only click on control points. Without some custom opengl drawing into the viewport to let you highlight normally unselectable points it is not imho doable. Such script is possible, but the answer I made is much easier.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Guess it's a useful feature request then.